# Limit UDP outbound traffic to loopback (localhost) instead of eth0

Tags: networking, vlc-media-player, iptables, udp, multicast

Atm i'm testing it on Ubuntu Server at VMware Workstation + Windows 7 local host with bridged connection. Later this has to go to live server.

I have VLC streaming video file on Ubuntu with

`cvlc -vvv /home/user/file.avi --loop --sout '#rtp{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.1.1.1,port=32321,caching=10000}'`

later this stream is picked by `udpxy` as

`udpxy -a lo -m eth0 -p 7777 &`

Basically everything works well but my hosting provider is counting the UDP traffic as outbound though i dont need it anywhere outside. My idea is to block multicast UDP outbound traffic.

I've tried to use

`route add -net 239.0.0.0/8 dev lo`

the traffic is limited (cannot access it outside) but the

`dumprtp 239.1.1.1 32321`

on same server is not working neither.

Also i've tried creating new loopback interface for multicast addresses in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this

```
auto lo lo:udp
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo:udp inet static
    address 239.1.1.1
    netmask 255.0.0.0
    network 239.0.0.0
```

I was just trying to get it work, but it does not.

So basically i want the multicast udp traffic stay inside server without going out to the exterior network. And it should be multicast udp (stream is also picked by storage system and stream quality tests).

Thanks.

Comment: have you looked into [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables)?

Comment: yes i did. My try was ``iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 239.1.1.1 --dport 32321 -o eth0 -j DROP`` and it blocks udp traffic completely. Including inside server. Cannot read it with ``dumprtp 239.1.1.1 32321``

Comment: hmm, yeah, that is weird... that rule should only block packets going to eth0. Maybe UDP always passes through eth0, since it is a network address. You can try creating a virtual network and sending udp packets to that network. so don't just create a udp loopback, you'll need to create an new complete interface with it's own IP-address.

Comment: That's what i've tried by creating new interface for loopback. Maybe i did it wrong? Is it valid to create static interface with address 239.1.1.1 ? That address is reserved for multicast only. But that is what i need to re-route from eth0.

Comment: Yeah, i don't think that interface is valid with a multicast address.

Comment: Well, i also tried ``ifconfig lo multicast`` converting loopback into multicast interface. Also created route rule to send upd to loopback, but it doesn't work. vlc cannot open lo interface to start streaming there.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a route on the multicast range to the lo interface like this? `ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev lo`. You might also want to [read up on multicast routing](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.multicast.html)

Comment: Seems like maybe you're starting to suffer from tunnel vision.  What is it that you're REALLY trying to do?  Have you considered TCP instead of UDP?  Are you sure UDP is multicast?  Multicast to loopback only seems a little silly, as a concept.  Often, trying to solve a problem, people will get caught up in the HOW to get there, completely forgetting that there may be some other way entirely to accomplish the real goal.  So, what is the real goal?  THAT may be far easier to solve.

Comment: We are talking about video stream server that is reading video file and converts stream to another format. There are several applications that are reading the UDP stream. One is `udpxy` that encapsulates it into TCP for customers. Another one is `dumprtp` that is saving the actual stream. Another one is "handmade" QA software.

Comment: Good thing that I decided to follow up and see if there was activity.  Hint:  If you "tag" a person with something like @killermist, it'll notify them that they've been responded to.  Anyway, on to business.  Shot in the dark, have you considered using "dst=127.0.0.1" (the authoritative localhost IP) instead of "dst=239.1.1.1" in the cvlc command?

Comment: @killermist effectively it does enclose multicast into lo (no traffic on eth0), but 127.0.0.1 is not multicast address. `udpxy` needs the source to be inside 224.0.0.1 - 239.255.255.255. It means, that i have to broadcast to 239.1.1.1 When i try read the stream with `udpxy` from 127.0.0.1 i get this error `set_multicast: setsockopt MCAST option: ADD: Invalid argument` Basically what i need is a way to bind 239.1.1.1 to `lo` interface. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it.

Comment: Just to clear out, that when i try broadcasting to 127.0.0.1 I DID convert `lo` into MULTICAST by `sudo ifconfig lo multicast` and i use this command to run `udpxy`: `udpxy -a eth0 -p 7777 -m lo -v` I think the solution is to create new virtual interface that is same as `lo` with multicast IPs routed there. But i don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Add new option `--miface=lo` to VLC: `cvlc -vvv /home/user/file.avi --loop --sout '#rtp{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.1.1.1,port=32321,caching=10000}' --miface=lo`
2. Add route to `lo` for multicas addresses: `route add -net 239.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev lo`

   2a. To make route persistent we have to add it to `/etc/network/interfaces` with prefix `up`. Like this: `up route add -net 239.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev lo`

That's it. Now VLC is streaming to `lo` interface and not to `eth0`. Also any application that wants to subscribe for 239.1.1.1 - 239.1.1.254 gonna do it through `lo` interface.

Hopefully this gonna help someone solve streaming issue.